# Should you send multiple thank you notes for multiple interviews?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process

I had an interview a few days ago and sent a thank you email. They sent back a positive response, but if they decide to move forward with me I'm anticipating at least 1 more interview, maybe 2.

Are you supposed to send a thank you note for every interview? If so how do you avoid being repetitive?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere That should probably be an answer but as I see it if you're going to send notes you typically would send one again if the same person ends up interviewing you later in the process. I don't see why you wouldn't express an appreciation for someone's time just because you did it once already.

Comment: Am I the only one who has never heard of a thank you note for an interview? I have never send such a thing and I didn't even know it would be expected (and I have the feeling it might not be in my country (Germany)).

Comment: @dirkk It's very much considered standard in US culture but is indeed rare in Europe. Here people typically only send a note if you have something more to say than "thank you for your time". But that is precisely what makes it a good thing to do here as it can show off your professional/courteous side where in the US it's almost expected these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would send a thank you after each stage. If possible, send them to the interviewer (s), but they may all be to the same person (recruiter or hiring manager). However, I would make them feel different (as opposed to the same two liner after each).

> RECRUITER,
>
> Thank you for taking the time to speak with me this afternoon and assess my fit for POSITION at COMPANY. Based on your explanation of the role, I believe EXPERIENCE could greatly assist COMPANY.

---

> RECRUITER,
>
> Please pass along my gratitude to HIRING MANAGER for providing valuable insight into POSITION. I look forward to meeting the team and discussing how EXPERIENCE can help PROBLEM.

---

> RECRUITER,
>
> I greatly enjoyed meeting TEAM MEMBERS this morning. I know they are busy and appreciate their time. I believe I would be a valuable addition to the TEAM. I look forward to continued discussion about joining COMPANY.

Answer (score 0):

No. This will make you seem like a brown noser and possibly someone who will be constantly seeking positive reinforcement. If your prospective boss likes those two things, then great, but it is a gamble. I suggest sending a thank you note after the first stage but, after that, let them pursue you---which brings to mind a third reason my answer is "No": you don't want to seem desperate. Reject Chris G's advice with confidence.

Comment: I'm curious, why does thanking people for their time make you a "brown noser" "constantly seeking positive reinforcement"? In an interview, you're selling something, following up on a sales call with a quick thank you and reinforcing a benefit is sales 101. You could absolutely try and be mysterious, aloof, and stand-offish, it's a valid sales tactic, but I would consider it far more risky.